# Fetch js function from webiew flutter and return data

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using [webview_flutter pacakge](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter),In this webview,where it shows a brochure of items,like vegetables,goods..etc,when you click on item from brochure it will popup it's details this is functionality here in app,so what i try to do is,i can show the brochure in app with flutter webview but  there is js function call `showAndroidToast(id)` when i click on an item it call the function and returns some data,it is working with pure android app,so we are replicating app to flutter for ios,but i cannot access the function it return following error when i click on item

**Error i am getting on webview created**

```
D/WebView (16639): evaluateJavascript=showAndroidToast()
I/chromium(16639): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: showAndroidToast is not defined", source: https://flyerbin.com/flyer/pick-of-the-day-3398 (1)
```

**Error After i click item in brochure**

```
I/BufferQueueProducer(16639): [SurfaceTexture-0-16639-4](this:0x9924e000,id:4,api:1,p:255,c:16639) queueBuffer: fps=3.65 dur=1097.05 max=742.36 min=33.99
I/chromium(16639): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "ReferenceError: webkit is not defined", source: https://assets.flyerbin.com/public/1602490675000/js/api.js (1)
```

**Js function in server**

[image]

**Code**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  WebViewController _controller;
 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://example.com',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller = webViewController;

          _controller.loadUrl('${baseUrl}flyer/$flyer_id');
        },
        onPageFinished: (String url) {
          _controller?.evaluateJavascript('showAndroidToast("Android")')?.then((result) {
         
            print("data" + result);
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Figured it out,you need to another condition in javascript to access data to flutter

Webview by using javascript channel you can access the js function,for flutter there to access data there is small change in js function,what i did here,if the key is Flutter it will return the id of a clicked item.

**Webview**

```
WebView(
            initialUrl: 'https://example.com/',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            javascriptChannels: Set.from([
              JavascriptChannel(
                  name: "Flutter",
                  onMessageReceived: (JavascriptMessage message) {
                    getSingleItem(message.message);
                  }),
            
            ]),
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller = webViewController;
              _controller.loadUrl('${Urls.baseUrl}flyer/${flyer_id}');
            },
            onPageFinished: (finish)  {
              setState(() {
                isLoading = false;
              });
            },
            gestureNavigationEnabled: true,

          ),
```

Use the data to another function

```
void getSingleItem(String id) async{

in this function you can do whatever you want,means that with data we got from the javascript function you can show a data to alert box with flutter...etc

}
```

Changes in JavaScript function

[image: data]

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to call `postMessage` and it returns data from dart code to js?

ex:

```
var x = Print.postMessage('Hello World being called from Javascript code'); 
alert(x);
```